# What is the minimum value of $\sqrt{\frac{2(x - 1)}{x}} + \frac{x + 1}{x}$, if $x > 1$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, functional-inequalities

What is the minimum value of 
$$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2(x - 1)}{x}} + \frac{x + 1}{x},$$
if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x > 1$?

Note that $f$ has a global minimum value of
$$f(1) = 2$$
if we allow $x \geq 1$.  (The WolframAlpha verification is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+sqrt%28%282%28x+-+1%29%29%2Fx%29+%2B+%28x+%2B+1%29%2Fx%2C+x+%3E%3D+1).)

A 2-D plot of the function for $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$ is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph+sqrt%28%282%28x+-+1%29%29%2Fx%29+%2B+%28x+%2B+1%29%2Fx).

Comment: You can't allow $\,0<x<1\,$ unless you want to talk of a non-real, complex valued function.

Comment: Conditions in title and question body are different.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, DonAntonio and Kaster.  I will edit my question accordingly - I apologize for the typos.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris  if $X>1$,there is no minimum ,but have a max. are you sure the question is right?

Comment: The function has no minimum. It has a maximum for $x = 2$ though.

Comment: $x \to +\infty $,$ f(x)=1+\sqrt{2}$, but it is not a minimum.

Comment: @chenbai, yes I am sure that I have phrased my question correctly.

Comment: @chenbai, can you please write more details for your last comment, and incorporate that into a formal answer?  Thanks!

Comment: I tried to double-check chenbai's claim using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit+of+%28%282%28x+-+1%29%2Fx%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29+%2B+%28%28x+%2B+1%29%2Fx%29+as+x+approaches+infinity), and I did get the same limit as $x \rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: @fuglede, can you write an answer (to include more details) on why the given function has a maximum for $x = 2$?  The 2-D plot given by WolframAlpha does not seem to agree with that observation.

Comment: After double checking W|A's 2-D plot, I realized that I was actually looking at the "Complex-valued plot" rather than the "Real-valued plot".  Looking at the latter one, I think I can believe the earlier assertions that the given function has a maximum value for $x = 2$.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris: This was answered by Unem below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{\frac{2(x - 1)}{x}} + \frac{x + 1}{x}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{2-\frac2x}-2\right)x+2}{2(x-1)x^2}$$

when $1\lt x\lt2$ , you can see that $f'(x)$ has a positive value and when $x=2$, $f'(x)=0$. when $x\gt2$ $f'(x)$ has a negative value. In fact, it has a max. value at $x=2$ but no min. value given that $x\gt1$. It is not actually strange, not every function has min. value.